# Bootstrap type ahead bind values with knockoutjs not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a ViewModel that I created with knockout which contains all the info for my product.
And It looks like this:

```
var ProductViewModelDS = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.ProductSKUID = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUID);
        self.ProductID = ko.observable(data.ProductID);
        self.ProductSKUStockCode = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUStockCode);
        self.ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber);
        self.ProductSKUName = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUName);
        self.ProductSKUPrice = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUPrice);
        self.ProductSKUSpecialPrice = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUSpecialPrice);
        self.ProductSKUIsOnSpecial = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUIsOnSpecial);
        self.ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty);
        self.ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty);
        self.ProductSKUCurrentStock = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUCurrentStock);
    }
```

I want to use the bootstrap type ahead, so that i can view the product info.
I found this **[Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rebond/archive/2012/07/18/knockout-js-binding-for-bootstrap-typeahead-plugin.aspx)** which gives me the event handler to do this.

But as soon as I start typing I get this error in my console:

***Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toLowerCase' bootstrap.js:1831
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 1***

This is my JSON I get from my AJAX call:

```
{
"d": [
    {
        "__type": "POS.Tracntrace.Member_Only.DAL.Models.CreateOrder.CreateOrderProductModel",
        "ProductSKUID": 15,
        "ProductID": 1,
        "ProductSKUStockCode": "BPUNIRM1131",
        "ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber": "600284403 1213",
        "ProductSKUName": "DSD 1131 Remote Control",
        "ProductSKUPrice": 84,
        "ProductSKUSpecialPrice": null,
        "ProductSKUIsOnSpecial": "false",
        "ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty": 1,
        "ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty": 10000,
        "ProductSKUCurrentStock": 100
    },
    {
        "__type": "POS.Tracntrace.Member_Only.DAL.Models.CreateOrder.CreateOrderProductModel",
        "ProductSKUID": 16,
        "ProductID": 2,
        "ProductSKUStockCode": "SDF213",
        "ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber": "55511545121",
        "ProductSKUName": "DSD 1132",
        "ProductSKUPrice": 599,
        "ProductSKUSpecialPrice": null,
        "ProductSKUIsOnSpecial": "false",
        "ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty": 1,
        "ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty": 10000,
        "ProductSKUCurrentStock": 100
    },
    {
        "__type": "POS.Tracntrace.Member_Only.DAL.Models.CreateOrder.CreateOrderProductModel",
        "ProductSKUID": 17,
        "ProductID": 3,
        "ProductSKUStockCode": "RPAIRDRHD",
        "ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber": "600284400 1018",
        "ProductSKUName": "HD PVR Remote Control",
        "ProductSKUPrice": 250,
        "ProductSKUSpecialPrice": null,
        "ProductSKUIsOnSpecial": "false",
        "ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty": 1,
        "ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty": 10000,
        "ProductSKUCurrentStock": 100
    },
    {
        "__type": "POS.Tracntrace.Member_Only.DAL.Models.CreateOrder.CreateOrderProductModel",
        "ProductSKUID": 18,
        "ProductID": 4,
        "ProductSKUStockCode": "1131",
        "ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber": "DSD1131",
        "ProductSKUName": "DSD1131 DVB-S",
        "ProductSKUPrice": 499,
        "ProductSKUSpecialPrice": 498,
        "ProductSKUIsOnSpecial": "false",
        "ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty": 1,
        "ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty": 10000,
        "ProductSKUCurrentStock": 100
    },
    {
        "__type": "POS.Tracntrace.Member_Only.DAL.Models.CreateOrder.CreateOrderProductModel",
        "ProductSKUID": 19,
        "ProductID": 5,
        "ProductSKUStockCode": "4660",
        "ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber": "DSR4660",
        "ProductSKUName": "DSR4660 HD DVB-S2",
        "ProductSKUPrice": 1499,
        "ProductSKUSpecialPrice": null,
        "ProductSKUIsOnSpecial": "false",
        "ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty": 1,
        "ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty": 100,
        "ProductSKUCurrentStock": 100
    },
    {
        "__type": "POS.Tracntrace.Member_Only.DAL.Models.CreateOrder.CreateOrderProductModel",
        "ProductSKUID": 20,
        "ProductID": 6,
        "ProductSKUStockCode": "DVR3000",
        "ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber": "MCSDPVR3000",
        "ProductSKUName": "DVR3000",
        "ProductSKUPrice": 1500,
        "ProductSKUSpecialPrice": null,
        "ProductSKUIsOnSpecial": "false",
        "ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty": 1,
        "ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty": 10000,
        "ProductSKUCurrentStock": 100
    },
    {
        "__type": "POS.Tracntrace.Member_Only.DAL.Models.CreateOrder.CreateOrderProductModel",
        "ProductSKUID": 21,
        "ProductID": 7,
        "ProductSKUStockCode": "DE45",
        "ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber": "N/A",
        "ProductSKUName": "ELSAT 45CM MILD STEEL DISH",
        "ProductSKUPrice": 560,
        "ProductSKUSpecialPrice": null,
        "ProductSKUIsOnSpecial": "false",
        "ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty": 1,
        "ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty": 10000,
        "ProductSKUCurrentStock": 100
    },
    {
        "__type": "POS.Tracntrace.Member_Only.DAL.Models.CreateOrder.CreateOrderProductModel",
        "ProductSKUID": 22,
        "ProductID": 8,
        "ProductSKUStockCode": "DE60",
        "ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber": "N/A",
        "ProductSKUName": "ELSAT 60CM MILD STEEL DISH",
        "ProductSKUPrice": 900,
        "ProductSKUSpecialPrice": null,
        "ProductSKUIsOnSpecial": "false",
        "ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty": 1,
        "ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty": 10000,
        "ProductSKUCurrentStock": 100
    }
]
}
```

I just want to be able to search for ProductSKUName, ProductSKUStockCode or ProductSKUManufactureStockCode.

Any Advice will be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <div class="well">
    <input type="text" data-bind="typeahead: { target: ProductViewModel, source: Products }" />
</div>
```

**Edit:**

My Javascript:

```
        ko.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var binding = this;
            var elem = $(element);
            var value = valueAccessor();
            elem.typeahead(
              {
                  source: function () { return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value.source); },
                  onselect: function (val) { value.target(val); }
              });
            elem.blur(function () { value.target(elem.val()); });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var elem = $(element);
            var value = valueAccessor();
            elem.val(value.target());
        }
    };


    var ProductViewModelDS = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.ProductSKUID = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUID);
        self.ProductID = ko.observable(data.ProductID);
        self.ProductSKUStockCode = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUStockCode);
        self.ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber);
        self.ProductSKUName = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUName);
        self.ProductSKUPrice = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUPrice);
        self.ProductSKUSpecialPrice = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUSpecialPrice);
        self.ProductSKUIsOnSpecial = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUIsOnSpecial);
        self.ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUMinimumOrderQty);
        self.ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUMaximumOrderQty);
        self.ProductSKUCurrentStock = ko.observable(data.ProductSKUCurrentStock);
        self.SearchText = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.ProductSKUName() + ' ' + self.ProductSKUStockCode() + ' ' + self.ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber();
        });
    }

    var ProductViewModel = function (Products) {
        var self = this;

        self.Products = ko.observableArray(Products);

        $.ajax({
            url: "CreateOrder.aspx/GetAvailibleProducts",
            data: '{}',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function (Result) {
                var MappedProducts =
              $.map(Result.d,
             function (item) {
                 return new ProductViewModelDS(item);
             }
               );
                self.Products(MappedProducts);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

        self.Save = function () {
            alert('Could Now Save: ' + ko.mapping.toJSON(self.Products));
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var VM = new ProductViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(VM);
    })
```

Comment: Whats your HTML with knockout bindings? It seems you have wrong datatype somewhere.

Comment: Added to Edit:      <div class="well">
        <input type="text" data-bind="typeahead: { target: ProductViewModel, source: Products }" />
    </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the link you provided, have you not got your target and source the wrong way round?

Basically, it appears that the type ahead plugin wants an array of string values it can use for the auto-complete suggestions. Add a SearchText property to the ProductViewModel that loops through all the products and puts the three fields you want into the searchterm array.

```
var ProductViewModel = function () {
    self.SearchText = ko.computed(function()
    {
        var searchableTerms = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Products(), function (item)
        {
            searchableTerms.push(item.ProductSKUName());
            searchableTerms.push(item.ProductSKUStockCode());
            searchableTerms.push(item.ProductSKUManufacturePartNumber());
        });
        return searchableTerms;
    });
};
```

Then update the html to something like:

```
<div class="well">
    <input type="text" data-bind="typeahead: { target: Products, source: SearchText }" />
</div>
```

Comment: If I switch them around, the input box gets populated with [object Object]. Also receive this error in the console: ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined bootstrap.js:1831
Typeahead.matcher bootstrap.js:1831
(anonymous function) bootstrap.js:1818
jQuery.extend.grep jquery-1.9.0.js:736
Typeahead.process bootstrap.js:1817
Typeahead.lookup bootstrap.js:1811
Typeahead.keyup bootstrap.js:1971
proxy jquery-1.9.0.js:801
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.0.js:3045
elemData.handle****

Comment: It will be populated with object, as you've bound it to your view model, which is an object. You need to add a computed observable that returns the text from the three fields you want to be searchable. I'll update my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: I get this Error when implementing suggested Fix. ****Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: SearchText is not defined;
Bindings value: typeahead: { target: Products, source: SearchText } knockout-2.2.1.js:5**** I will update my Question to reflect my Entire ViewModels and Ajax Call. Might it be that the Element is created before the Knockout Model?

Comment: Ah, that's because you are binding to the Products view model, which doesn't have the SearchText property. I'll have a think about how you can go through the array in your typeahead method.

Comment: Should I perhaps enforce the Seachtext From my SQL (I can just add an EF Query for SearchText) so essentially it would just access searchtext as another property. Also just as a side note, how will I add the Product Info to lets say a table after the correct search has been identified?

Comment: Hang on, is this functionality just to offer autocomplete for the input box?

Comment: Essentially yes.. and provide some sort of search capability Here is example of type ahead: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: See updated code. This should provide the text you need for the autocomplete now.

Comment: I get this error after updating. I believe it's because the Ajax call get's executed after element binding, just a hunch ****Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined****

Comment: @JacquesBronkhorst I think that this should work now, moved the search text property exclusively to the ProductViewModel.

Comment: Well the good news it seems to work, the bad news: On first start-up the Searchbox Still populates with [Object].[object] but when I remove it and type In Product it functions As auto complete which is perfect. If I remove the [object].[object] and click somewhere else on the page, it completely clears my JSON result set. I am currently building a fiddle to demonstrate this

Comment: @JacquesBronkhorst Ok, I'll have a look when it's up. I think it's time to move this discussion to chat now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24105/discussion-between-paul-manzotti-and-jacques-bronkhorst)