# Bootstrap TypeAhead 2.2.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using twitter bootstrap 2.2.2 for my MVC web app. I'm trying to have a auto-complete functionality. TypeAhead seems pretty close to what I want to do but I'm unable to find how to use it for complex object along with Ajax data source. I've seen couple of typeahead forks on github but that don't seem to work with bootstrap 2.2.2.

I really don't see the use of this control if its not meant to be for complex entities though I'm sure this can't be the case and I've read bootstrap 2.2.2 does support ajax but I m unable to figure out howto use it. Any guidance in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example

Comment: @ken this is the exact thread that I was talking about in my question.

Comment: Have a look at this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723820/bootstrap-type-ahead-bind-values-with-knockoutjs-not-working/14727540#14727540

Comment: @PaulManzotti that all passed over my head. I just only wish if  bootstrap bit more sample documentation available somehow.

Comment: @PaulManzotti I followed your answer it seems to work for complex objects but that all the data is already pulled on the client which violates ajax surpose isn't it?

Comment: @afr0 I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean! That example is using an ajax call when creating a ProductViewModel object to get the data.

Comment: @PaulManzotti in the solution you shared all the data is on the client side already... so when you search the search is performed on the client side, whereas I'm looking for something that will search complex data on the server side and returns only that relevant data.