# Twitter's Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to trigger Typeahead when i populate the search box from my knockout view model function.

Here is a js Fiddle that demonstrates my problem. When i click on the submit button the search field gets populated with the word 'apples' but typeahead does not get triggered.

```
    <div>
    <input id="btnSearch" data-bind='value: search'>
    <br>
    <button id="btnSubmit">Send String to Search Box From Here</div>

    function ViewModel() {
    this.search = ko.observable("");
    this.call = function () {
        this.search('apples');
    }
}

vm = new ViewModel();

var data = ["apples", "bananas", "peaches"];
$("#btnSearch").typeahead({
    source: data
});

$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    vm.call();
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8nps/4/

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the typeahead with typeahead instead of val()

```
$('#searchVendor').typeahead('setQuery', 'value-you-want-to-set');
```

or better yet

```
jQuery#typeahead('setQuery');
```

I would interpret this in your code as -

```
$#searchVendor(myValue()); || $#searchVendor('mike');
```

It is a GitHub'd issue https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/247

Comment: I did come across that and tried it yesterday and then realized it uses typeahead.js, unfortunately what i'm using here is the 'bootstrap twitter typeahead' and this approach does not seem to work.

Comment: You realize that Bootstrap is called Twitter Bootstrap and uses jQuery's typeahead correct?  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#plugins

Comment: If it is not working for you consider creating a fiddle and I can show you how to do it from JavaScript.

Comment: I get it now and yes I was confused. Let me give it a shot and see what happens. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried $('#searchVendor').typeahead('setQuery','Mike'); I get a message stating object has no method 'setQuery'. I came across the below link and the second comment has confused me even more. https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/361

Comment: Try the third way I mentioned please, of course choose one or the other not both.

Comment: I just updated my question and created a fiddle to make life easy! Thanks for any help! Much appreaciated.

Comment: Hey take a look at this link and see if it helps you at all.  Also, you have a lot of tag errors in your Fiddle that are making the DOM mad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723820/bootstrap-type-ahead-bind-values-with-knockoutjs-not-working  By the way, I see your problem now that because you are assigning value as an observable you can't set the value and have everything still work.  Have you thought about not using the value binding and instead using target and source like Paul mentions in that link?